# How many total users and total "voting" users does SFF have?

Tags: discussion, users, site-statistics, data-explorer

I'm sure there's a Data Explorer query for this, but it's been many years so I'm hoping someone more proficient has one handy. I'm looking for two stats:

- Total SFF.SE users
- Total SFF.SE users who ever cast at least one vote.

Comment: Total users can be seen directly from [the reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/186/alltime/scifi), under "Total Rep" for 1+. Note that as someone might have noticed [from the user list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate), it includes no-activity users, including profile spammers...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't believe SEDE exposes who has or hasn't voted as votes themselves are hidden within it. However, we can check if a user has the [Supporter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/6/supporter) or [Critic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/7/critic) badges for first up and down vote respectively. Using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1700257/percentage-of-users-who-have-voted?minRepuation=0) we see that we get the following values:

| TotalUsers | Users Who Have Voted | % Of Users Who Have Voted | Users Who Have Upvoted | % Of Users Who Have Upvoted | Users Who Have Downvoted | % Of Users Who Have Downvoted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125490 | 27935 | 22.26 | 27887 | 22.22 | 4008 | 3.19 |

Obviously these results come with the usual constraints where unregistered users don't show up (I believe), deleted users won't show up etc.

If you want to tweak the results based on reputation just alter `minReputation` to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: Your precision is a little high lol

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Just float precision, couldn't be bothered to add another `CAST` in there just for display purposes.

Comment: Well, you can edit the text lol

Comment: The downvote percentage is lower, presumably because it is inaccessible to 101 rep users (who do have enough rep to upvote). Still, 3% seems *very* low.

Comment: @Kevin Personally, it took me a long of time before giving my very first downvote (3 years later). I usually just don't upvote when I feel like there's still some level of effort.

Comment: @Kevin: Unlike on more technical sites like Stack Overflow or even rpg.stackexchange, it's rarer that answers have overall negative value, which is one (common?) criterion for downvoters.  And when they do, some people may feel that it already having an overall negative score is low enough, and a sufficient signal to future readers.

Comment: @Kevin: 22.26 / 3.19 is about 6.97, so about 1 in 7 users who have ever voted even once have cast a downvote.  I'd guess many users get here from HNQ with 101 rep, enough to upvote but not downvote.  If we set the minRep to 125, 70.7% voted, 25.7% downvoted (1 in ~3 of users who ever vote and are capable of downvoting.)